# PowerApps - Creating a Date Range

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am learning to use [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/). While learning, I'm trying to create a form that includes two data cards: a start date and an end date. When a user chooses a start date, I want the end date to automatically be set to one week in the future. However, I still want the user to be able to set the end date. My question is, how do I automatically set the end date when the user chooses the start date?

Comment: Do you have follow-up questions?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two date-pickers, set the `OnSelect` property of **DatePicker1** to assign the calculated new date to a variable `calculatedDate`.

**Snippet:**

```
UpdateContext({calculatedDate:DatePicker1.SelectedDate + 7})
```

[image]

Set the `DefaultDate` property of **DatePicker2** to `calculatedDate` variable. That's it.

[image]